# First Differencing to remove seasonality and trends

Tags: python, time-series, arima

I am trying to remove seasonality and trends from my time series data. I found this post that said to use df_diff = df.diff().diff(12).dropna() (https://www.tobiolabode.com/blog/2020/12/30/how-to-convert-non-stationary-data-into-stationary-for-arima-model-with-python). I don't understand why we need to use diff(12) from pandas. Could someone explain this to me? Thanks!

Comment: Before copying any code, how do you know your data has some sort of seasonality? Can you show us? I would also recommend reading what `diff` does and finally Google ARIMA and in particular Autocorrelation.

Answer (score 1):

Since the data is recorded every month (i.e. a data point for each month in the year) and we see a yearly seasonality trend we compare the data for the same month against previous year. This is done by taking the difference against the data from last year (`.diff()`), which is equal to going back 12 observations since each observation is data for a specific month.

Comment: So are you saying (1) df_diff_1=df.diff() takes the difference against the data from last year, then what's the purpose of doing the second step (2) df_diff_2 = df_diff_1.diff(12)?

Comment: The `.diff()` method in general takes the difference between the current row and some previous row (depending on the value provided for the `periods` argument). Since there is a yearly seasonality we want the difference compared to 12 months (which is 12 observations in this case) back, and therefore use the value of 12 for the `periods` argument and use `.diff(12)`.

Comment: Does this first differencing include trends and seasonality removal?

Comment: First differencing is used to remove the trend, after that another difference is taken for 12 periods based on seasonality pattern. See also [this page](https://nwfsc-timeseries.github.io/atsa-labs/sec-tslab-differencing-to-remove-a-trend-or-seasonal-effects.html) which shows the same but explicitly splits the two steps.

Comment: Okay. After reading the link you sent, I'm confused a little. If we want to remove the yearly seasonality, why don't we just do df.diff(12)? Why do we have to initially call diff() before diff(12)?

Comment: If you just want to remove seasonality then using just `.diff(12)` is sufficient (in the case that there are no other seasonalities that need to be removed), however the example also wants to remove the trend, for which another `.diff()` is used with the default value for the `periods` argument.

Comment: That makes sense. Another question, what other ways can first differencing be used for to help make a time series stationary?